# Unable to Bypass Activation Screen S5

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, activation

I've tried every combo I've seen for bypassing the S5 Galaxy (SMG900VZKV) Samsung's activation screen.  Phone is Verizon branded.  Anyway around this screen with 4 corners or volume button presses?  Or any other combo?  I've tried them all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove sim, boot and select run on wifi.  :)